# I am trying to switch this code to use the front camera

Tags: ios, iphone

I am new to programming, and trying to fix this code to use the front camera instead of defaulting to the back.  I'm not sure what I need to change to make this work properly.

Here is my sample code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
[session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];

AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice = [AVCaptureDevice       defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
NSError *error;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:inputDevice error:&error];

if ([session canAddInput:deviceInput]) {
    [session addInput:deviceInput];
}

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc]  initWithSession:session];
                [previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
                                            CALayer *rootLayer = [[self view] layer];
                                            [rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
                                            CGRect frame = self.frameForCapture.frame;

[previewLayer setFrame:frame];

[rootLayer insertSublayer:previewLayer atIndex:0];


stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
[stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

[session addOutput:stillImageOutput];

[session startRunning];
```

Comment: See the _Device Characteristics_ section of the [AV Foundation Programming Guide: Media Capture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice = [AVCaptureDevice       defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
NSError *error;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:inputDevice error:&error];
```

With this:

```
NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVCaptureDevice *frontCamera;
for (AVCaptureDevice *dev in devices) {
    if (dev.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
        frontCamera = dev;
        break;
    }
}
if (!frontCamera) {
    NSLog(@"No front camera found!");
    // Handle no front camera error
}
NSError *error;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:frontCamera error:&error];
```

Comment: @Rob - Didn't realize there was a position property, I updated my code.  Thanks for the suggestion!